# How to authenticate a subset of routes in ring application?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I have two sets of [compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure) routes, public ones, which need no authentication, and private ones which need authentication.

```
(defroutes public-routes
  (GET "/" [] homepage-handler))

(defroutes private-routes
  (GET "/secrets" [] secrets-handler))
```

I created a middleware which checks is the user authenticated and either continues the middleware chain or raises.

```
(defn wrap-must-be-authenticated [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (if (authenticated? request)
      (handler request)
      (throw-unauthorized))))

(def app
  (-> private-routes
      (wrap-must-be-authenticated)))
```

This works fine, all "private routes" require authentication.

How would I go about adding the `public-routes` so they are excluded from `wrap-must-be-authenticated`?

I believe `defroutes` returns ring handlers, so I'm thinking I need to do something like:

```
(-> (wrap-must-be-authenticated private-routes)
     public-routes)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to put multiple `routes` definitions in a containing `routes`, and wrap (`wrap-routes`) the appropriate routes in middleware to restrict access:

```
(def all-routes
  (routes
    (-> #'private-routes
        (wrap-routes wrap-must-be-authenticated))

    #'public-routes

    (route/not-found
      (:body
        (error-page {:status 404
                     :title "page not found"})))))
```

Another example from a project where I'm using buddy.auth's `restrict`:

```
(defn wrap-admin [handler]
  (restrict handler {:handler (fn [req]
                                (boolean (get-in req [:session :admin?])))}))

(def app-routes
  (routes
    (-> #'admin-routes
        (wrap-routes wrap-admin)
        (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-csrf)
        (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-formats))
    (-> #'home-routes
        (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-csrf)
        (wrap-routes middleware/wrap-formats))))
```

Comment: Thanks - what does `#'` mean?

Comment: That uses the `var` for your route definitions, which can help if you want to edit/reload code while you're running the app. Instead of binding the routes to a static value, they'll be resolved from the var which can change after the app starts. FWIW you don't have to prefix the routes with `#'`.

Comment: As written, you consult the private routes first, and they will throw an exception if the user is not authenticated. You will never successfully serve an unauthenticated user a public page.

Comment: @amalloy I'm using this same setup in a Compojure app and it works fine for auth'd routes and otherwise. I am however using a different middleware function than the OP that returns `{:status 401}` instead of throwing.

Comment: I'm not sure why but the first example does work even when `throw-unauthorized` is called. I'm only guessing but it might have something to do with some ring middleware which captures exceptions where the `::type` key can be mapped to a HTTP status.